# Proving that a function satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|^3$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, functions, holder-spaces

Let $\mathbb R$ be the set of real numbers and $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be such that for all $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $$|f(x)-f(y) |\leq |x-y|^3.$$ Prove that $f(x)$ is a constant.

This is a new type of problem for me and I feel I am missing some trick to simplify the given expression. Any help??

Comment: The stated condition means that $f$ has a derivative everywhere, which can be found by using the definition of derivative.

Comment: Related questions: [link 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603291/how-to-show-some-function-is-constant), [link 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865365/function-is-defined-on-the-whole-real-line-and-fx-fy-leq-x-y-alpha), [link 3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762692/classifying-functions-that-satisfy-fx-fy-leq-mx-y-alpha?rq=1), [link 4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252037/prove-f-is-constant-if-fx-fy-leq-mx-y-alpha?rq=1), [link 5](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164804/show-f-is-constant-if-fx-fy-leq-x-y2)

Comment: And also [link 6](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113674/proof-of-a-simple-property-of-real-constant-functions).

Answer (score 4):

The limit definition of the derivative says that $f'(y) = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to y}\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ (provided the limit exists).

Here, we have that $\left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right| < |x-y|^2$. What does this tell you about the derivative of $f$?

Comment: Now, I understand the value of derivative is zero, but I am still confused about the absolute value.

Comment: What about the absolute value is confusing?

Comment: @JimmyK4542: check the fundamental definition of the derivative at a point $a$.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version without derivatives.

Choose $x,y$. Let $t_k = x+{k \over n} (y-x)$, for $k=0,...,n$.

Then $|f(x)-f(y)| \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |f(t_{k+1})-f(t_k)| \le (x-y)^3 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {1 \over n^3} = {1 \over n^2}(x-y)^3$.

Since this is true for all $n$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)| = 0$, or in other words, $f(x) = f(y)$.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I was wondering how you get that $(x-y)^3 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {1 \over n^3} = {1 \over n^2}(x-y)^3$?

Comment: The summand is not a function of $n$.

Comment: so why don't we have $(x-y)^{3}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {1 \over n^3} \le \dfrac{1}{n^{2}}(x-y)^{3}$ instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. $\sum_k {1 \over n^3} =  n {1 \over n^3} = {1 \over n^2} $.

Comment: At first, I thought that since the summand is not a function of $n$, that meant that $\sum_{k} \dfrac{1}{n^{3}} = \dfrac{1}{n^{3}}$

Comment: Sorry, I meant not a function of $k$.

Comment: Should $t_{k}$ should be equal to $x+ \dfrac{k}{n}(y-x)$ instead?

Comment: @K.M: Yes indeed. Thanks for catching that!